# SQL Server : setting the value to the next highest id number when the table is not set to auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and some times SQL Server 2012 and I need to do an insert on a pre-existing database where the schema does not seem to have the id column set for auto-increment.

So for example, here is a basic table `My_Table` that I have:

```
[Id]  [Name]
-------------
 1    JOHN
 2    BOB
 3    SALLY
```

I need to do an insert to get the MAX value of the last Id and then use this value for my new insert statement. I believe this is the best approach.

So for example the "pseudo syntax" for the insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO My_Table 
VALUES(MAX(Id) + 1, 'MIKE');
```

How is the best way to do this when the Id is not set in the table schema to auto increment?

**Note:** I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL 2008 and/or could be done on SQL 2012.

Comment: well what version are you using? if it is 2012 then you have the option to use [`SEQUENCE OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)

Comment: Needs to also work the solution in 2008

Comment: If you don't have an `identity` column, and you cannot change that, and you need to have this running in SQL Server 2008 - good luck! Doing a `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` is a **horribly bad practice** and will **NOT** be reliable & workable in a busy multi-user system, as it will result - rather sooner than later - in duplicate values. You *could* put a unique constraint on that `ID` column and then some of your inserts might fail, if they got a duplicate value - but that's not a really convincing solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend changing the structure of the table to use an identity column.  The table definition should be:

```
create table my_table (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This is the right solution.  If you can't do that, you can express the logic as:

```
insert to my_table (id, name)
     select coalesce(1 + max(id), 0), 'Mike'
     from my_table;
```

However, this suffers from race conditions.  Two threads could attempt an insert at the same time and end up with the same `id`.  Avoiding such race conditions is why you want the database to do the work.

If you are in control of all inserts into the table, you can use a sequence as well.

Comment: I cannot change the table structure. Need to leave it "as-is"

Comment: The second example using the "coalesce" will do exactly what I need for this specific scenario. I appreciate your input.

Comment: Could the race condition be alleviated by placing the second statement within a Transaction?

Comment: @DavidDubois . . . You would have to lock the entire table and that can have a big impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

You could create another table with an `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE ID_Insert (
    ID INT IDENTITY(234, 1) primary key,
    Val smallint null
)
```

(Where your seed value will be `MAX(ID) + 1`)

Insert any value into this table:

`Insert ID_Insert(Val) values(NULL)`

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the ID of the inserted value and use that in your insert into your other table.

NOTE: I have not tested this, but it gets around all the issues raised so far, so any criticism is welcome.

Comment: I like your idea, but I cannot add new tables. I have to work with what I have. I appreciate your idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the table structure so that the `Id` is an `IDENTITY` column, then this is probably your best bet:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @maxId int = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table);

INSERT INTO my_table (id, name)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) + @maxId, name
    FROM my_other_table;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This works for batch inserts, not only single name inserts.